# Factory implementation issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I am trying to create a service, and this is it:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('appService', Service);

    function Service($http) {

        function getData() {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open('GET', 'mock.json', false);
            request.send(null);

            return [request.status, request.response, {}];
        }

        return {};
    }
})();
```

Where `mock.json` is in the same folder.

Then I try to call it from a controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app')
        .controller('appCtrl', appCtrl);

    /** @ngInject */
    function appCtrl(appService) {
        console.log(appService.getData());
    }
})();
```

But it gives me an error:

> TypeError: appService.getData is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning empty object, thus you are getting the expected error.

```
function Service($http) {

    function getData() {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', 'mock.json', false);
        request.send(null);
        return [request.status, request.response, {}];
    }

    //Here return the function reference of getData
    return {
        getData : getData
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing to return the object with the proper properties on your `Service`

```
return {
  getData: getData
}
```